# VS 2010 beta 2: ASP.NET MVC2 project cannot add Areas

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2

I have installed VS 2010 beta 2 on my Vista Home Premium 64-bit edition laptop. I was so excited on MVC 2 but to my disappointment, I cannot add Areas to the MVC 2 project. Anywone experiencing this too? Or is it only me?

I would love to hear some info / walkthrough on how to fix this problem. Thanks!

**EDIT: added screenshot**

[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/4009/mvc2w.jpg](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/4009/mvc2w.jpg)

Comment: I don't have any problem adding areas.  What have you done and what is it telling you?

Comment: just added a screenshot, all i did was install VS 2010 beta 2, create a MVC 2 application and tried to add Areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987(VS.100).aspx) on adding areas in ASP.Net MVC 2 on MSDN