# "Add" option missing commands in MVC 2 RC project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on this project which was created using ASP.NET MVC 2 RC.
The "Add" has disappeared when I right click on the files.
My problem is similar to this:

[VS 2010 beta 2: ASP.NET MVC2 project cannot add Areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136074/vs-2010-beta-2-asp-net-mvc2-project-cannot-add-areas)

but the WalkThrough answer didn't help.
example: "Add" option is there for "Controllers" folders but "Add -> Controllers" is missing. There is no "Add" for individual files at all.

Note: I do not have any problems if I create new MVC 2 projects. So the problem is not with the VS installation.

Please help!! Thanks

Comment: there isn't supposed to be an "add" option for individual files!

Comment: ...what about the "Add -> Controller" option when I right-click on the "Controllers" folder?

Comment: are you by chance experiencing this while the project is running under VS (e.g., in Debug mode)?  If so, that's normal.  VS doesn't allow changes to code while running an MVC app by default and commands like Add -> Controller aren't available when running an MVC app in Debug mode.

Comment: yes there is no Add for individual files... but the project is not running. its just open in VS. Everything was ok but something most have gone wrong few days ago which. I tracked the history and there is nothing unusual about the changes that others in the team have made about the code!!

Answer (score 0):

*not the answer.
The only way which I thought would work was to create a new solution inside the old solution and copy/overwrite all the files from the old one to the new one. I got the Add options back but got 100+ referencing errors when I tried to build/run the project. So don't try this.